# How to call a function in render() using a parameter that's defined in return()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, onclick, react-props

I'm struggling with calling the method `deleteItem`.

Here is the sandbox that show's the issue I'm having. https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-rgb-or7om

If you click on the blue `delete` button, the card is deleted from the view, which is basically what I need to happen, except the behavior I'm looking for should be to first click the kebab icon and then delete using the button in the dropdown.

I've added an `onClick={() => deleteItem(item)` to the `DropdownItem` component in the `kebabDropdownItems` const variable -- it tells me that `item` is not defined, which makes sense, since it's defined in `map`. I've tried removing the `kebabDropdownItems` variable and just putting those components in the `dropdownItems` prop of the `Dropdown` component, directly with the `onClick` method.

But that doesn't work either, the menu items just don't show up at all. I tried putting the array of cards into its own `const` within the render method, which also didn't work.

What am I missing?

Comment: `deleteItem` is curried, so your code should be `onClick={this.deleteItem(item)}` https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-thompson-iilqs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works when you define the `DropdownItem` component directly in the `Dropdown` component like this:

```
<Dropdown
  isPlain
  position="right"
  onSelect={e => this.onDropdownSelect(key, e)}
  toggle={
    <KebabToggle
      onToggle={isDropdownOpen =>
        this.onDropdownToggle(key, isDropdownOpen)
      }
    />
  }
  isOpen={this.state[key]}
  dropdownItems={[
    <DropdownItem
      onClick={this.deleteItem(item)}
      position="right"
    >
      {" "}
      Delete
    </DropdownItem>
  ]}
/>
```

See the entire [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-sammet-vwsjg)

Comment: This does work! I see you put it into an array as well -- which I think was what I was missing. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 2):

The variable item is outside of this.state.cards.map, you need create kebabDropdownItems as a function and pass item as parameter. My suggestion:

```js
// create outside of render

function kebabDropdownItems(onClick) {
  return [
    <DropdownItem onClick={onClick} position="right">
      {" "}
      Delete
    </DropdownItem>
  ];
}

// change dropdownItems to

dropdownItems={kebabDropdownItems(this.deleteItem(item))}
```